# Access S3 bucket after logging on Cognito from other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I have two AWS accounts. The account A has a Cognito identity pool configured with roles for Authenticated and Unauthenticated.

The trusted relationship policy for Authenticated role looks like this:

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<identity_pool_id>"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`

There is also a policy for Authenticated role that looks like this:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::users-pictures/public/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::users-pictures/protected/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::users-pictures/private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::users-pictures/uploads/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::users-pictures/protected/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "public/",
                        "public/*",
                        "protected/",
                        "protected/*",
                        "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/",
                        "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::users-pictures"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}`

On account B I have an application that must authenticate on Cognito from account A, but needs to access a bucket on account B.

This application uses Storage from Amplify.

The bucket structure must be something like this:

`users-pictures/private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*`

When Amplify authenticates on account A and tries to access this bucket on account B, it gets an Access Denied (403).

Probably it's missing some configuration on account A and/or account B.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html  follow this guide

Comment: I've just taken a look at this guide, but I think it is applicable to root/IAM users only. In my case the user belongs to Cognito Federated Identities.